# createUserWithEmailAndPassword VUEJS error updating user profile

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, authentication, vuex

i have this issue with a firebase app i'm also developing , my intentions are to create an user and update his profile with a name using the firebase method createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
I evolve the process and eventually it works but also throws an error which says kind of :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property user of undefined
>   at eval (index.js?xxxx)
>   at e.g (auth.esm.js?xxx)
>   at kc (auth.esm.js?xxxxx)
>   at gc (auth.esm.js?xxxxxx)
>   at B.k.Zb (auth.esm.js?xxxxxx)
>   at Qb (auth.esm.js?xxxx)

despite of having already modified the user info, then i need to refresh the page to get this error to dissapear.
Here part of my code:

```
        signUserUp({ commit }, payload) {
           commit("settingLoader", true);
           firebase
             .auth()
             .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
             .then(() => {
               let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
               console.log(user);
               user
                 .updateProfile({
                   displayName: payload.name
                 })
                 .then(usermod => {
                     const User = {
                     id:usermod.user.uid,              undefined usermod
                     email:usermod.user.email,         undefined usermod
                     name:usermod.user.displayName     undefined usermod
                   };
                   commit("settingUserIn", User);
                   commit("settingLoader", false);
                 });
             })
             .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
               commit("settingLoader", false);
             });
         }
```

Then the error does reference to an eventual undefined "usermod" for user.uid, user.displayName ,and user.email.
Any advice about what i'm missing?
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile

Firebase's `user.updateProfile` method returns a void promise, meaning it returns a promise with no value.

You still have access to your `user` variable in your `then`, so why not just change it to

```js
...
   user
                 .updateProfile({
                   displayName: payload.name
                 })
                 .then(() => {
                     const User = {
                     id: user.uid,              
                     email: user.email,        
                     name:user.displayName
                   };
                   commit("settingUserIn", User);
                   commit("settingLoader", false);
                 });
...
```